# Bootloader Functionality in Context of JOS and significance of the MBR signature

Tags: assembly, bootloader, osdev, bios

I'm currently learning about operating system development, following the OS course from MIT. Most tutorials on bootloaders in forums like osdev wiki was using a signature, commonly referred to as the Master Boot Record (MBR) signature (0xAA55), at the end of the bootloader code. However, the bootloader code provided in the JOS repository seems not using the signature yet it is able to load.

Here is the code snippet from the JOS bootloader (boot/boot.S):

```
#include <inc/mmu.h>

# Start the CPU: switch to 32-bit protected mode, jump into C.
# The BIOS loads this code from the first sector of the hard disk into
# memory at physical address 0x7c00 and starts executing in real mode
# with %cs=0 %ip=7c00.

.set PROT_MODE_CSEG, 0x8     # kernel code segment selector
.set PROT_MODE_DSEG, 0x10    # kernel data segment selector
.set CR0_PE_ON,   0x1     # protected mode enable flag

.globl start
start:
 .code16           # Assemble for 16-bit mode
 cli             # Disable interrupts
 cld             # String operations increment

 # Set up the important data segment registers (DS, ES, SS).
 xorw  %ax,%ax       # Segment number zero
 movw  %ax,%ds       # -> Data Segment
 movw  %ax,%es       # -> Extra Segment
 movw  %ax,%ss       # -> Stack Segment

 # Enable A20:
 #  For backwards compatibility with the earliest PCs, physical
 #  address line 20 is tied low, so that addresses higher than
 #  1MB wrap around to zero by default. This code undoes this.
seta20.1:
 inb   $0x64,%al        # Wait for not busy
 testb  $0x2,%al
 jnz   seta20.1

 movb  $0xd1,%al        # 0xd1 -> port 0x64
 outb  %al,$0x64

seta20.2:
 inb   $0x64,%al        # Wait for not busy
 testb  $0x2,%al
 jnz   seta20.2

 movb  $0xdf,%al        # 0xdf -> port 0x60
 outb  %al,$0x60

 # Switch from real to protected mode, using a bootstrap GDT
 # and segment translation that makes virtual addresses
 # identical to their physical addresses, so that the
 # effective memory map does not change during the switch.
 lgdt  gdtdesc
 movl  %cr0, %eax
 orl   $CR0_PE_ON, %eax
 movl  %eax, %cr0

 # Jump to next instruction, but in 32-bit code segment.
 # Switches processor into 32-bit mode.
 ljmp  $PROT_MODE_CSEG, $protcseg

 .code32           # Assemble for 32-bit mode
protcseg:
 # Set up the protected-mode data segment registers
 movw  $PROT_MODE_DSEG, %ax  # Our data segment selector
 movw  %ax, %ds        # -> DS: Data Segment
 movw  %ax, %es        # -> ES: Extra Segment
 movw  %ax, %fs        # -> FS
 movw  %ax, %gs        # -> GS
 movw  %ax, %ss        # -> SS: Stack Segment

 # Set up the stack pointer and call into C.
 movl  $start, %esp
 call bootmain

 # If bootmain returns (it shouldn't), loop.
spin:
 jmp spin

# Bootstrap GDT
.p2align 2                # force 4 byte alignment
gdt:
 SEG_NULL               # null seg
 SEG(STA_X|STA_R, 0x0, 0xffffffff)  # code seg
 SEG(STA_W, 0x0, 0xffffffff)        # data seg

gdtdesc:
 .word  0x17              # sizeof(gdt) - 1
 .long  gdt               # address gdt
```

Given the absence of the MBR signature in this bootloader code, I have the following questions:

1. How does the BIOS recognize and load the bootloader code from the disk without the MBR signature?
2. In the context of BIOS-based booting, what is the significance of the MBR signature?

I appreciate any good resources or explanations regarding this topic. Thank you!

Comment: It's possible the signature is added in a linker script. You have to show the commands used to build this into a binary.

Comment: I don't know JOS, so make sure to inspect the generated binary to see if the signature is there. It may be added with some macro trickery or by a script. The BIOS (when set in CSM) will load the first sector of the boot device. It may use other heuristics besides the classic signature but it's a bet. Without that signature, most BIOS won't execute the bootloader. I find it hard to believe the MIT wrote a bootloader without a signature, maybe there's some context missing.

Comment: @MargaretBloom & ecm Thanks! I went back to check the source code and found something interesting in the Makefrag. There's a line that runs a Perl script [sign.pl](https://github.com/phlalx/jos/blob/master/boot/sign.pl) in the boot directory. This script is where the signature is added.